# Steam adds an extra input device

Tags: usb, steam, input

Steam adds an emulated Xbox controller while there is also "Sony Interactive Entertainment Controller"(DS4) so some games that have native support for DS4 recognize there being 2 players. How can I get rid of or disable the one that does not use Steam controller configs as I need them (I'm assuming js0)?

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices` gives:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=054c Product=09cc Version=8111
N: Name="Sony Interactive Entertainment Wireless Controller Touchpad"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-13/input3
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-13/3-13:1.3/0003:054C:09CC.0004/input/input22
U: Uniq=a4:53:85:8c:89:6e
H: Handlers=mouse1 event21 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=2420 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=054c Product=09cc Version=8111
N: Name="Sony Interactive Entertainment Wireless Controller Motion Sensors"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-13/input3
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-13/3-13:1.3/0003:054C:09CC.0004/input/input23
U: Uniq=a4:53:85:8c:89:6e
H: Handlers=event22 
B: PROP=40
B: EV=19
B: ABS=3f
B: MSC=20

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=054c Product=09cc Version=8111
N: Name="Sony Interactive Entertainment Wireless Controller"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-13/input3
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-13/3-13:1.3/0003:054C:09CC.0004/input/input21
U: Uniq=a4:53:85:8c:89:6e
H: Handlers=event23 js0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=20001b
B: KEY=7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3003f
B: MSC=10
B: FF=107030000 0

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=28de Product=11ff Version=0001
N: Name="Microsoft X-Box 360 pad"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input24
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event24 js1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=20000b
B: KEY=7cdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3003f
B: FF=10000 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. I am very happy that you not only solved the problem in your question but also provided the solution in an answer. We don't put SOLVED, RESOLVED, FIXED, etc. in the question title. After the required waiting period please click on the gray check box ✓ next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark your answer as the correct one and the question solved. This will also help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing event23(in my case); "sudo rm /dev/input/event23"